# What is the preferred way to work with ElasticSearch in Play! scala project

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, elasticsearch

I have a Play! scala project and I want to use Elastic Search.
I see that there are several clients to work with Elastic Search from Scala (http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/community/current/clients.html).
But, since I write scala in Play! framework, I see that there is Play! plugin for ES (https://github.com/cleverage/play2-elasticsearch).

What is the recommended way to work ? Pros/Cons ?

10x,

Answer (score 2):

I didn't find any of the clients particularly appealing and instead just use Play's excellent asynchronous HTTP client to deal with Elasticsearch's REST API.